# jquery window.scroll doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

[in this page](http://firatabak.com/trying/tur_detay.html) I have 3 `window.scroll` functions but my events  isn't working properly but if I remove another 2 `window.scroll` the very first `window.scroll` function works as expected.My jquery codes are in below

```
 $(document).scroll(function() {
      var y = $(this).scrollTop();
      if (y > 800) {
        $('.sizi-arayalim').fadeIn();
      } else {
        $('.sizi-arayalim').fadeOut();
      }
    });

    $(document).scroll(function() {
      if (!$("#aniStickyNav").length) {
     return false; //Check if the element exist
  }
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (y > $(".after-scroll-sticky").offset().top+$(".hotel-search-box").height()) {
    $('#aniStickyNav').show();
  } else {
    $('#aniStickyNav').hide();
  }
});

$(document).scroll(function(){
    if(!$(".hotel-search-box").length){
        return false;
    }
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
      if (y > $(".hotel-search-box").offset().top) {
        $('.sticky-checkin').show();
      } else {
        $('.sticky-checkin').hide();
      }
});
```

Comment: Could you also show the html and say which scroll is meant to work in what way exactly? I.e. More details please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `if (!$("#aniStickyNav").length) {
     return false;`
without putting into scroll function, 
and try to combine others into just one.

Comment: how it can be possible ?

Comment: you sure that is about it ? nothing change :)

Comment: wait a second something change :))

Comment: according to my experience, in.most of cases.. that was the main issue..

Comment: it works thank but I want to ask logic why it work like this ?